# NUnit/Resharper 2016 failing to resolve relative path

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I do not know who is the culprit here but I have this following line of code in a test class:

```
var sut = new PatientSearchService(@"\data\patientinfo.csv");
```

In the test project, I have a folder called data, within which is a file named patientinfo.csv marked as content and always to be copied.  In the Debug folder for the test project, this data folder and patient info file exists.  However, when I execute the test, someone, do not know whether it is Resharper, NUnit or Visual Studio 2015, is converting that relative path to

> c:\data\patientinfo.csv

instead of a relative path.  Backward or forward slash does not matter.

Can't believe this is a problem in 2016, but I may have missed some train.  What is going on here anyone?

Comment: Is this NUnit 3? Tests aren't necessairily run in the root dll location (Debug folder) - use `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` to get the dll dir.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. The path @"\data\patientinfo.csv" is not relative, it's absolute. Probably, you mean to leave off the initial slash. So the code is doing exactly what you told it to do.
2. A relative path won't be resolved to the location of your assembly, if that's what you want. You have to combine it with the assembly location, as Chris noted.

Comment: I would also watch out for tests being run using "Shadow Copy". Both NUnit and R# have this option (the OP is asking about NUnit; but I'm mentioning this in case the reader is using the R# test runner). If that option is enabled, then the test may fail since the assemblies may be copied to a "shadow copy" for testing; but they will not necessarily be accompanied by any resources that you might expect to be at a relative location. Switching off "shadow copy" means assemblies will be tested where they are located.

Comment: I've long held that code that can't run either with or without shadow copy, is in error. Others have disagreed as you might expect. :-)